# Why does my php code not retrieve the field I want from the mysql results?

Tags: php, sql

I am a beginner in php and mysql. I am trying to extract a particular field from a query result called "`tweet_id`" and send it as a parameter to a constructor of class "`Tweet`". The problem is the constructor seems to only recognize an empty string being passed to it. Why does my code not pass the correct `tweet_id`? Am I somehow getting a hold of the record wrong?

```
$myquery = "select tweet_id from tweets";

$result = $DB->query($myquery);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
}

$tweet = new Tweet($row["tweet_id"];
```

Comment: What database library are you using?

Comment: OP, Did my answer below help you?  If it did, would you mind giving me a checkmark?

Answer (score 1):

Lots Of bugs:

1. You're setting `$tweet` outside your `while` loop
2. `$tweet` is missing the `$` variable prefix
3. Lots of missing closing parentheses `)`

Try this and see if it fixes everything for you:

```
$myquery = "SELECT tweet_id FROM tweets";
$result = $DB->query($myquery);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tweet = new Tweet($row["tweet_id"]);
    print_r($tweet);
}
```